# How do I write in a JavaScript prompt message using WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, alert

I want to write some text in Javascript Prompt. I tried following code to run javascript prompt. How do I fill a value in the prompt using selenium/webdriver?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.javascripter.net/faq/prompt.htm#top");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'Try it now']")).click();

Alert javascriptprompt = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();
javascriptprompt.sendKeys("How do I write in a JavaScript prompt message using WebDriver?");
```

Comment: i think the question is about the next line in the code which will fill in a value, say '20', in the javascript prompt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not very thoroughly documented, but:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Some text");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

The [`Alert`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#sendKeys%28java.lang.String%29) interface, the [`switchTo()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo%28%29) method.